# navigation outside the navigator not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm getting myself familiar with the new react-navigation version. I'm seeing an issue while using the navigation.navigate method.

Current Behavior

When we click the menu button, it throws an error -
Device: (65:24) undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')
Expected Behavior

On clicking the menu button, it should open the drawer
How to reproduce

https://snack.expo.io/W0dye1bLt

Comment: Having gone through the snack, I realized that the core issue is having both a Drawer Navigator (containing Home, Notifications) and a custom TabBar in the form of FooterComponent that is also meant to navigate between Home, Notifications etc. This duplication is rarely seen and far from ideal UX -- that is why React Navigation does not support it. I would reconsider this approach. Perhaps your Drawer is not meant to contain links to Home or Notifications, but something else altogether? Then you could use it and nest a real Tab.Navigator inside instead of using refs and the FooterComponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `FooterComponent` is rendered inside the NavigationContainer, it is not a screen or inside any navigator, so it will not have the navigation context available, and it will not be able to get the navigation prop from `useNavigation`.

However, there is a workaround for this particular problem, where you create a ref for your NavigationContainer and pass that ref to the FooterComponent. This is described in detail in [the "Navigating without navigation prop" section of React Navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop). Applied to your snack, it would require the following changes (plus the relevant imports):

```
const Navigator = () => {
  const navigationRef = useRef();

  return (
    {...}
      <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
        {...}
        <FooterComponent navigationRef={navigationRef} />
```

```
const FooterComponent = ({ navigationRef }) => {
  {...}
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigationRef.current.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())
      }>
```

You can then use the same approach with `navigationRef.current.navigate('Notifications')` or `navigationRef.current.navigate('Home')` for other tabs.

You can see this applied to your snack here: https://snack.expo.io/POeoVzAsG

Comment: Thanks Marek for reverting back. I tried using useNavigation but still it doesn't work. Wil lit be possible for you to edit my expo Snack above with the correct code?

Comment: Hi, took another look at the Snack, and I see now that the issue with the answer is `FooterComponent` is rendered outside of any navigator, and so `useNavigation` cannot return the navigation object. I will update the answer with some thoughts and an example workaround.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mark. This really helps